# How to change Bootstrap Grid with media queries?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I am trying to work out the best way to deal with removing content when resizing the screen using media queries. However, I am using the Twitter Bootstrap grid system and it is making it a bit tricky so I would appreciate some pointers.

Lets say I have the following basic grid:-

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="left-content" class="span6">
            Left Content
        </div>
        <div id="right-content" class="span6">
            Right Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use css media queries so that when the screen width is reduced to a certain size then I want to hide the `#right-content` which is straight forward like so:-

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #right-content {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

However, I really need to update the class on `#left-content` from `span6` to `span12` so that the content is as wide as the screen. I can obviously do this with JavaScript but can this be done with pure css?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.0 has additional grid classes that you can use: `.col-sm-12` and `.col-md-6` should work for you. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Your right column can simply use the classes: `.hidden-xs .hidden-sm` (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="left-content" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        Left Content
    </div>
    <div id="right-content" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-6">
        Right Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to upgrade to Bootstrap 3.0. Lots of improvements were made.

From the 3.0 docs, here are the responsive utilities that do exactly what you need.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

And making a column fill the width of the screen at small sizes is as simple as adding the class `col-md-6` to your div. Check out the 3.0 docs for the grid system.